# why using mirror modifier my mesh is is becoming wierd?

Tags: rendering

[image][image]I am trying to create a pikachu in blender but for the body I am using mirror modifier under subsurf modifier , but when I put mirror modifier over subsurf modifier the leg part merges and I do not know what I did wrong . kindly help I am adding images for better perspective.[image]

Comment: Could be flipped normals or inner faces, or duplicated vertices. The Subdivision Surface modifier smoothes the bad areas and the Mirror modifier mirrors it. The result is this "butt shape". With the monitor icons right next to the modifiers' names you can turn them off in the viewport. How does the mesh look like if you turn them off?

Comment: like this @Blunder i have added an image

Comment: Ah ok, there are the feet. If you go to the side view (numpad 3) you will see the upper part of the mesh is open and the lower part is closed, right? The question is, do you want to have one solid smooth mirrored block, or are you already modeling the feet in the "weird area"? If you want to have a solid block then remove the inner face.

Comment: thanks @blunder